# Ajax issue on rounding long int

Tags: ajax

I've this kinda of id, received from a $_GET

```
72157637114842303
```

If I pass in Ajax (recalled at bottom of my page php in this mode)

```
<script> var id = <?php echo (string)$id; ?></script>
<script src="/js/ajaxcalling.js"></script>
```

And this is the "ajaxcalling.js" file:

```
$.ajax({
        url         : location.protocol + '//' + location.host + '/flickr_json.php',
        data        :   {
                            type    : 'photoset',
                            id      : id
                        },
        dataType    : 'json'
    }).done(function (result) {
```

It pass to `flickr_json.php`  this value (i imagine rounded!)

```
72157637114842300
```

How i can solve my issue? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Terrible mistake from my side.... :(

```
<script> var id = <?php echo $id; ?></script>
```

must be

```
<script> var id = "<?php echo $id; ?>"</script>
```